# How to compute a single feature vector from an array of MFCC features

Tags: python, speech

I recently started to learn about signal processing with the objective to do some machine learning on signals. I wish to extract features with Mel frequency cepstral coefficients (see wikipedia page, stackoverflow won't let me post more than 2 links) and then use a Bayes classifier.

I have found the following librairy which seems to do the exact thing that i want (http://python-speech-features.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It even comes with a pretty good tutorial on MFCC (http://www.practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/).

Now, let's get to business. By my understanding, i am supposed to get a 1d vector of coefficent for each signal. The function mfcc in python-speech-features returns a matrix of shape (number of frame X number of cepstrum). There is also the logfbank function that returns a matrix of shape (number of frame X number of filterbank).

Now i am slightly lost on how to, from the signal and the functions mfcc and logfbank, get the vector of feature i am supposed to train my model on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: The right answer depends on what do you want to learn from the signal. For example, if you want to identify speaker, you can compute GMM distribution with few gaussians that fits the signal, parameters of distribution (means and variance) would give you a simple speaker identity vector. There are more complex methods, for example, factorized speaker vector which removes environment variability. Overall, such questions fit http://dsp.stackexchange.com better.

Comment: I will post further questions there. thank you for fixing the title and for your input.